# git commit id in Visual Studio ISO C code?

Tags: git, visual-studio

We would like to add the git commit id to the --version output of our programm (pure console app, ISO C, no GUI).

With gcc/Makefile/Linux it is easy to get the git commit id as ISO C preprocessor symbol (e.g. $ gcc -DMYGITTAG="$(git describe --always)" ... # etc.), but how can I do this with Visual Studio 19 on Windows 10 as compiler?